# Multiple times Event subscribed when I clicked a page from Navigation Bar in ionic 3 . How to fix this?

Tags: ionic2, ionic3

When first time app launch then one time event publish and one time subscribe but when I am calling same page from Navigation Bar then multiple times event subscribes like 4 , 5 times .

Anyone Know , How to fix this issue ? Thanks in advance.